# What are these strange black lumps on basil plant?

Tags: diseases, fungus, basil, parasites, leaf

I've recently noticed these lumps on the stems of my basil plant

The fall off fairly easily but I'm not sure what they are and there's not much online that I can find.

[image: These lumps]
[image: These lumps]

Comment: Do you have a magnifying glass? They look a bit like slugs of some kind, but it's tough to tell.

Answer (score 1):

They appear to be slugs or snails. Unclear which from these pictures. Snails have shells, slugs don't; both are gastropods and eat vegetation. Picking them off into a container of soapy water is one way to reduce the damage they do. There are other methods as well, some more hazardous to other things.

The second one is in the middle of typical slug/snail damaged area.